# Fragment still visible after popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `MainActivity` there is a `FrameLayout` (id=fragment_container) that is replaced by the Activity in `onCreate` with `FragmentA`. `FragmentA` just contains a single Button and calls onClick in the `MainActivity` in order to replace the `FrameLayout` with `FragmentB`. `FragmentB` contains a RecyclerView and is shown correctly. I call `fragmentManager.popBackStack()` to bring back `FragmentA`. Now `FragmentA` is shown on top of `FragmentB` (which I still can interact with).

Why is `FragmentB` not removed after calling `popBackStack`?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentB());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //...

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentA fragment = FragmentA.getInstance(this); //register OnClickListener
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
//...
}
```

**FragmentA**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public FragmentA() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        return view;
    }

    public static FragmentA getInstance(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        fragmentA.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return fragmentA;
    }

    private void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    //...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FragmentB, container, true);
        //manipulating Views...
        //...

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a background color to fragment A.

Comment: @JpCrow wouldn't that be a dirty workaround?

Comment: If you prefer you can add it in the theme of your activity, then inspect with the developers tools the overdraw of that fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `FragmentB` class. You should not pass the argument `attachToRoot=true`.

Try this instead:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    //...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //don't pass true
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FragmentB, container, false);
        //manipulating Views...
        //...

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [popBackStackImmediate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate()) instead,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

From the [popBackStackImmediate docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate()),

> Like popBackStack(), but performs the operation immediately inside of the call. This is like calling executePendingTransactions() afterwards.